# WIX 4 - MSI package keeps showing installation window on the second run of the package

Tags: wix

I migrated from WIX 3 to the WIX 4 newest version and have two problems:

1.
In WIX 3 second run of the package displays message: "Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue"

In Wix 4 it just shows installation window again for already installed package.

2. The msi package put in the bundle is installed correctly but when I try to uninstall the bundle it shows installation window of MSI package instead (in add / remove programs).

The header for MSI package:

```
<?define ProductCode = "{D664299C-3BF0-413C-8F69-A1F92EEF95D6}"?>
<?define UpgradeCode = "{2970E2D4-EB34-4E67-879A-9734A33DA46F}"?>

<Package Name="App test" Language="1045" Version="$(var.BuildVersion)" Manufacturer="Company" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" InstallerVersion="200" ProductCode="$(var.ProductCode)">
```

The bundle:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal" xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util"
xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx" >
<Bundle Name="Test app" Version="$(var.BuildVersion)" Manufacturer="Company" UpgradeCode="914e7e96-34a1-4130-9608-ce6c7aec7139">
<BootstrapperApplication>
```

I can uninstall the msi issuing the command:

```
msiexec /x {D664299C-3BF0-413C-8F69-A1F92EEF95D6}
```

What is wrong with that?

--UPDATE

Ad2. I noticed strange behavior. When I removed app from add/remove window the installator ran installation window with Install button then it went all the way and uninstall .. everything ..

Maybe it has to do something with that line?

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="../package.msi" Vital="yes" bal:DisplayInternalUICondition="1" Visible="no" />
```